# How to print element number and content of element with NoParent BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I´m trying, without success yet, to identify the element (paragragh/element number and its content) that is NoneType and that has no parent.

This is my sample [input.html](https://jsfiddle.net/vosp6abk/) file, where the paragraph that triggers the error is the 3rd one within second table.

Below is my current code and the error I get:

```
fp = open("input.html", "rb")
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html5lib")

i=0
NoneType = type(None)
for elem in soup.find_all('font'):
    i=i+1
    target = elem.findParent().findParent()
    target.decompose()
    if target is NoneType:
        print(i)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findParent'
>>>
```

If I remove the line `target.decompose()`, the error doesn´t appear, so it seems the issue is with this command. But even if I remove the line `target.decompose()` and try to print the element number
with `print(i)`, it doesn´t print anything.

What can I do to identify the elements with no parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop runs three times (because `soup.find_all('font')` results in a selection of 3 `font` nodes). Each loop's `decompose` wipes out the grandparent of the then-current `font` node.

In the first loop, the grandparent of the current `font` node is `<p align="left">`; the `decompose` eliminates that node (including the first `font` node), leaving the two remaining `font` nodes.

The grandparent of the 2nd (now first) `font` node is `<TR>` (**not** `<p align="left">`, like in the first node, because the first node had a `<b>` between itself and `<p align="left">`; this current `font` node is a direct child of `<p align="left">` and the parent of that node is `<TR>`).  The `<TR>` node includes within itself as grandchildren both remaining `font` nodes, so the current `decompose` eliminates both at once.

By the time the 3rd loop is executed, `soup` no longer has any `font` nodes, so there is no `elem` for that loop; consequently, no grandparent either.

Comment: Hi Jack, I think I understand your explanation, but for example, if the HTML file has only the first paragraph in html and I run the script, I don't get error. If the HTML file has only the 3rd paragraphs, the error appears. Why does that happen?

Comment: @GerCas - if you remove two of the three `<p align="left">` nodes (regardless of which two), the output of `soup.find_all('font')` is now the 1 `font` node remaining. The `for` loop then only runs once, removing the grandfather of that one remaining node and exits without an error.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. In understand better what is going on.